# (Ubuntu -Firefox- default font) How make default font arial in Firefox on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I don't like Ubuntu Firefox default font, I want to put Arial font like in Windows.
What should I do for that(I don't have Arial font in Firefox fonts list)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arial is in the msttcorefonts (Microsoft TrueType core fonts) package, which you can install by typing this line into the console:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

If you want to change the font in Firefox only, open up Firefox, go to Edit > Preferences, select the Content tab and choose Arial as the default font. If you want Ubuntu to use it elsewhere, open up System > Preferences > Appearance in your top panel and select the Fonts tab. You can now pick Arial for any group you want.

Comment: After I run sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
I get:

 Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Do you have synaptic, the update manager or anything else open, that is related to package/software handling? In fact, the error tells you quite clearly, what's happening (it's one of the better examples for error messages.)